# Yii2 Validating an empty array (null array)

Tags: php, validation, yii, yii2

I have this scenario where I have a form as follows:

```
public $selling_price;
public $numbers;
public $inventory_factor;

public function rules() {
    return [
        ['selling_price'], 'integer'],
        [['inventory_factor'], 'safe'],
        ['numbers', 'each', 'rule' => ['integer']],
}
```

I have this last validation rule to make sure that I get an array of integers. This works fine when the input is a string for example. IT does not work though if an array [null] is sent. This for example does not throw errors

```
{
  "selling_price": 2200,
  "numbers": [null]
}
```

Using vardumper, gives the numbers array to be

```
[
    0 => null
]
```

Is there way in Yii2 through which I can either remove(filter) the null values from the array before starting, or validating those as well?

Comment: Show us the code where you are triggering validation. Are you sure the validation is actually being executed? It is odd that you have printed here your data as an illegal JSON string with trailing comma

Comment: Yes Im sure that the validation is run completely. I just removed un-necessary parts from the json. But Ill update this, thanks for the comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having looked at the special topic for the core validators, I see that under the [each](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-core-validators#each) validator it shows:

> rule: an array specifying a validation rule. The first element in the array specifies the class name or the alias of the validator. The rest of the name-value pairs in the array are used to configure the validator object.

Also, for the yii\validators\EachValidator, which extends [yii\validators\Validator](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-validators-validator#$skipOnEmpty-detail) it has a property `$skipOnEmpty`, which defaults to `true`:

> $skipOnEmpty public property
>   - Whether this validation rule should be skipped if the attribute value is null or an empty string.
>
> public boolean $skipOnEmpty = true

So, accordingly, you need to tweak your rule as follows.

```
['numbers', 'each', 'rule' => ['integer', 'skipOnEmpty' => false]],
```

Now your validator for `numbers` will not turn a blind eye to the values in the array that are empty - if it finds any empty or non-integer values, the validation will fail.

Comment: Thank you very much this is exactly what I wanted

Comment: Glad to help! Yii2's documentation is fantastic, sometimes it does take a bit of perseverance and digging for exactly what you want but 99% of the time it is all there :)

Answer (score 1):

['numbers', 'integer', 'min' => 0]

This will Validate that the value is an integer greater than 0 if it is not empty. Normal validators have $skipOnEmpty set to true.

Reference : https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-validation

in this Data Filtering topic you can refer for these

Comment: Hm, according to docs, 'min' specifies "the lower limit (inclusive) of the value", which I think means that `'numbers', 'integer', 'min' => 0]` will validate that the value of the integer is greater than OR equal to 0?


Reference: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-core-validators#integer